# SAPUI5 local scope object as formatter function parameter

Tags: javascript, formatting, sapui5

How can local scope objects pass as parameter into formatter functions. I only know how to pass values from the binding into the formatter function but I need to pass additional objects from local scope into the formatter function.

```
            // request the order operations and bind them to the operation list
            oView.getModel().read(sPath + "/OperationSet", {
                success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                    if (oData && oData.results) {
                        var oOrder = oView.getBindingContext().getObject();
                        // I need sOrderType inside the external formatter function
                        var sOrderType = oOrder.OrderType;

                        operationList.bindAggregation("items", {
                            path: sPath + "/OperationSet",
                            template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                                title: "{Description}",
                                info: "{DurationNormal} {DurationNormalUnit}",
                                visible: {
                                    parts: [{path: 'Activity'}],
                                    formatter: de.example.util.Formatter.myFormatterFunction
                                }
                            }),
                            filters: []
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (oData) {
                    jQuery.sap.log.error("Could not read order operations");
                }
            });
```

Comment: oMyObject is constant irrespective of your binded values?

Comment: No oMyObject is created with other view information.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

Also bind to other values that contain the same information as the one in oMyObject

Create a closure to capture oMyObject and make it available inside the formatter. e.g.:

```
 formatter: ((function(oObject){
                //oObject is available inside this function
                return function (firstName, lastName, amount, currency) { // all parameters are strings 
                    if (firstName && lastName && oObject.someProperty == null) {
                        return "Dear " + firstName + " " + lastName + ". Your current balance is: " + amount + " " + currency;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            })(oMyObject))
```

Store the information in oMyObject somewhere in the model and access that model inside the formatter function (although a bit of an antipattern)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply call the local object from inside your formatter context.

Say you have:

```
var sString = "Test";

oTxt.bindValue({ parts: [{
    path: "/firstName",
    type: new sap.ui.model.type.String()
        }, {
    path: "/lastName",
    type: new sap.ui.model.type.String()
        }, {
    path: "/amount",
    type: new sap.ui.model.type.Float()
        }, {
    path: "/currency",
    type: new sap.ui.model.type.String()
        }], formatter: function (firstName, lastName, amount, currency) { 

console.log(sString);

// all parameters are strings 
    if (firstName && lastName) {
        return "Dear " + firstName + " " + lastName + ". Your current balance is: " + amount + " " + currency;
    } else {
        return null;
    } } });
```

This will properly log the sString as "test".

If you are talking about a variable that is local in a completely different place (e.g. a different view or controller), then you have to be more specific about from where to where you want your variable in order to get the best answer.

Comment: This conclusion does only work if I implement the formatter function inline in the same function block. I adapt my source code to represent the problem. I give you +1 because the solution works for my previous sample code

Comment: In this case, I would do the following: upon the changing of the "sOrderType", add this as a property to your model (oModel.setProperty(sNewPath, sOrderType));

In your formatter function bind parts (e.g. this answer), of which one path is set to your newly set property. Everytime the property changes, the formatter function will automatically be updated. When nothing is set, the string will return undefined, and otherwise the string will return your string value.